# How to calculate difference between saved timestamp and current time

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I saved a timestamp in this format .

[image]

So what I want to do now is calculate the difference between the current time and the saved timestamap in a JavaScript function. But I have no idea how to do that.

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: so this seems to be a custom time format? do you have it as a string or json?

Comment: its not a atring us saved as a timestamp in firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fetch the document, 'timestamp' field would be of type [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#seconds) and you can use `seconds` property and current timestamp to calculate the difference as shown below:

```
const snap = await getDoc(docRef);
const timeDiff = Date.now() - snap.data()?.time.seconds * 1000;

console.log(`Time Difference: ${timeDiff} ms`)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very easy to achieve. Most important to know is that the function [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns you the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

To get the duration between to timestamps is like "end - begin = duration".

Here is a code example:

```
// collect the first timestamp
const beginTimestamp = Date.now()

// here comes a for loop to consume some time, otherwise you will get 0 milliseconds
for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    "Some kind of string".split("").reverse().join("")
}

// collect the second timestamp
const endTimestamp = Date.now()

// subtract the first from the second timestamp tells you the milliseconds in between of both timestamps
console.log("Duration in milliseconds:", endTimestamp - beginTimestamp)
```